# What is the difference between major, prime and primary?

Tags: difference

1.**Major/prime/primary** purpose of a computer.

2.It is commonly employed in, and considered a **major/prime/primary** characteristic of, systems.

3.They were a **major/prime/primary** supplier of sarin to the U.S. military in the 1950s.

4.This is our **major/prime/primary** target.

Comment: Pretty sure a dictionary will help you here.

Comment: *Major* is a comparative, *prime* and *primary* are superlative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jack O'Flaherty is correct, but unfortunately the language (especially in the technology fields) isn't that consistent. People frequently use all three words interchangeably, even though they shouldn't.

Your examples all use a single characteristic. That simplifies the explanation.

---

**Major:** implies there is a group of characteristics that are more important than others and the identified characteristic is a member of that group.

> Calculation is a major purpose of a computer.

*The above sentence would suggest that calculation is one of many uses of a computer and frequently the reason a computer is used, but someone should expect to see the computer used for many other purposes.*

---

**Primary:** implies there is a group of characteristics, but the identified characteristic is more important than all of them.

> Calculation is the primary purpose of a computer.

*The above sentence would suggest that calculation is one of many uses of a computer and often the only reason the computer is used. Someone should expect to only occasionally see the computer used for other purposes.*

It is inappropriate to use "purpose" with the indefinite article because "primary" is a superlative. So, it would be unusual to say "Calculation is *a* primary purpose..." (but not unheard of).

The word "major" can have the same meaning as "primary" when "purpose" is definite. "Calculation is *the* major purpose...."

---

OK, Prime is... well... *squishy.* It has a mathematical meaning (first in a list of things). It also has the context of *nothing being better than this.* ***In many ways, *prime* and *primary* are synonyms.*** But, perhaps artistically, there is a difference.

**Prime:** implies more than importance, it implies that the characteristic is more suitable than all others. It could be said that it is the only characteristic that matters.

In the examples you've provided, it would be used *artistically* more than *scientifically.* I'd expect to see it in marketing brochures but not in technical specifications.

> Calculation is the prime purpose of a computer.

*The above sentence would suggest that calculation is only practical reason to use a computer. Someone using a computer for another purpose would be eccentric.*

One should never use "prime" in an indefinite context ("a prime purpose..."). If you're tempted to use "prime" in the indefinite, choose to use "primary."

But you'll hear people use it that way anyway....